# Get the last instance in a month using moment.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I've been using `moment.js` to get the last and first instances in a month. For example, the last Monday in a month, last Tuesday, last Wednesday, etc.

I need to get the actual dates for a scheduler I already have created.

The problem I'm facing is the way `moment.js` looks at the last week of a month.

[image]

In this instance, If I try getting the last Wednesday of a month, I'm getting the dates 01/01/2020 and 01/04/2020 because of the way `moment.js` views the last week of a month.

The way I'm doing it is similar to this:

```
let date = moment().add(i, 'month').endOf('month'); // To get the end of the month
let newDate = date.day(3).format('YYYY-MM-DD 03:00:00'); // To get Wednesday
```

It works for some months, but not for those that have an overlap. Is it possible in `moment.js` to only focus on the last week of the month so that it only ever looks at dates between the 21st - 28th if February and 24th to 31st for all other months?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For last `Wednesday` use `-4` (7 - 3)

`3` **(positive)** - current week wednesday

`-4` **(negative)** - previous week wednesday

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/

```js
var date = moment().add(1, 'month').endOf('month')
console.log(date.day(date.day() >= 3 ? 3 : -4).toString())

var date = moment().add(2, 'month').endOf('month')
console.log(date.day(date.day() >= 3 ? 3 : -4).toString())

var date = moment().add(3, 'month').endOf('month')
console.log(date.day(date.day() >= 3 ? 3 : -4).toString())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```